# R Forecast package for anomaly detection

Tags: r, model, detection, forecasting

I'm trying to detect anomalies from training data.

First, I train a model according to a given time series using the `forecast package`:

```
train <- forecast(ts(sin((2*pi)*seq(from=0,to=10,by=0.01)),frequency=100))
```

Then, once I get new time series i try seeing how well they fit the trained data, and by that finding anomalies.

Currently I'm using the `accuracy` function which doesn't seem to be the right tool for the job:

```
test <- ts(sin((2*pi)*seq(from=0,to=20,by=0.01))+sin((3*pi)*seq(from=0,to=20,by=0.01)),frequency=100)accuracy(train,test)

accuracy(train,test)
```

I also thought of somehow analyzing the residuals of the new dataset according to the trained model.

Does anyone have any good ideas as to how to optimize this task?

Comment: Could you provide some code? I find it hard to say with  just a package and a function name.

Comment: So your problem is not about how to make it work and it is about how to improve a code and/or the way to analyse residuals. For statistics there is [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/), and this for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Correct me if I am wrong, but there you will get more help, or at least even with the code I can not help you.